# GCP - CDC fetch failed: We couldn't connect to the MySQL server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-datastream

I configured a DataStream in GCP to replicate data from MySQL to BigQuery. It was working successfully for some time and initial data sump is successful to BQ, but after that, I keep on getting the error,

```
{
  "insertId": "c8c68035-bd9b-4e5d-a350-5abf2bc33163",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "event_code": "MYSQL_CDC_FETCH_FAILED",
    "message": "CDC fetch failed: We couldn't connect to the MySQL server 35.196.212.155 on port 3306 as our request timed out. Make sure that the connection info is correct, the host is up and reachable on that port, and Datastream IPs were allowlisted..",
    "original_message": "(2003, \"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (timed out)\")",
    "read_method": "mysql-cdc-binlog",
    "context": "CDC"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "datastream.googleapis.com/Stream",
    "labels": {
      "location": "us-east1",
      "resource_container": "projects/444429740053",
      "stream_id": "replication-stream-json"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-09-19T06:21:18.932065Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/*****/logs/datastream.googleapis.com%2Fstream_activity",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-09-19T06:21:19.879866597Z"
}
```

I use IP whitelisting in MySQL to read from DataStream. I see the pipeline in the failed state now and this is what it looks like,

[image: failed datastream]

But if I choose a particular table from the object page and choose "Initiate Backfill", it still works.

[image]

I don't have any clue about this behavior and would appreciate any help/directions on this.

Edit: Adding further observations, I'm having 2 SQL MySQL instances in ClouSQL. One is very active (lots of updates/inserts/deletes) and another one is inactive. And the problem of incremental changes replication happens only on the active instance, if I make some changes manually (to see if replication happens) in the inactive instance it's getting replicated to BQ in around 15 mins.

Comment: Can you try this [tutorial](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/22950?parent=catalog) to replicate data from MySQL to BigQuery?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT That was the tutorial I followed to set this up

Comment: This issue apprears to be transient issue, can you try restarting the Datastream?

Comment: I tried restarting it multiple times and even recreating it multiple times. But that doesn't help me with this problem @PrajnaRaiT

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT Thanks for the reply. I'll raise a support ticket, and I'm also adding further observation to the question